# New SE site for Programming Language Design

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

As Bioacoustics is one of the newest SE sites, many of you might remember the process that's in place for getting a new site approved, and many of you might remember how exciting it is to be one of the first users of a brand new SE site.

After Bioacoustics went live almost a year ago, the only site that has gone live was Solana, which I didn't think overlapped enough with Bioacoustics to notify the community here.

However the [Programming Language Design](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127456/programming-language-design-and-implementation?referrer=NjE4NDEyZTRhYWI0MTA0NGZiMTI5MDZlZDhhMDk1MjE2OGM5Y2I2OGExYTQwNTFiNzAwZjc5OGEzZmE3OTQyOJyrV3dVI5xVz9VEVF0LfiP1mv6kDbcQB8iTVOM2FU-f0) proposal, which has begun with a ***very healthy start*** is one that I think a lot of people here might find interesting.

If you are excited about the launch of a new site, or curious to experience contributing to a brand new site, or otherwise have interest in participating in a new site about programming language design, I encourage you to [visit the proposal for Programming Language Design SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127456/programming-language-design-and-implementation?referrer=NjE4NDEyZTRhYWI0MTA0NGZiMTI5MDZlZDhhMDk1MjE2OGM5Y2I2OGExYTQwNTFiNzAwZjc5OGEzZmE3OTQyOJyrV3dVI5xVz9VEVF0LfiP1mv6kDbcQB8iTVOM2FU-f0) and to click on "commit"!  If you haven't ever done this before, make sure to click on "sign up" instead of "log in", but you won't have to do much more because Area51 will sign you up based on your existing SE credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, after reading through Qs and comments (e.g. "Why did language 'x' choose to have feature 'y'"), this is a sort of SE that I like to avoid for finding useful information. It seems that anything that addresses "design and implementation" is prone to fights on interpretation, opinions, and even semantics or "religious" believes. OK, it fun to read and useful for distraction, but otherwise... Also, a lot of "Should" questions, the usefulness is questioned, will very likely results is fundamentalistic discussion.

Comment: The site is live now. You can check it out in action to see if you have any second opinions. Link: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127456/programming-language-design-and-implementation/visit